# Google Analytics filter not working

Tags: google-analytics

I send all my events to the same Google Analytics account and use profiles with filters to filter them out.

**My staging filter isn't working properly**. Here it is, pretty simple:

---

[image]

---

**Here are my events, in the `All Traffic` profile** (no filters):

[image]

---

Based on my filter, the events with the hostname `stagingsecure.example.com` should show up in the `Staging` profile. But they don't.

Any ideas why these events don't show up in my `Staging` profile?

Comment: What other filters do you have on the staging profile? Any other include filters?

Comment: Make sure you are looking at a time frame after the filter was implemented, and please post what the report in `Audience -> Technology -> Network -> Hostname` is showing.

Comment: @Rimbaud I'm sure that I'm using the right timeframe, because I'm seeing the events in the "All Traffic" profile. Regarding the report you want, all the hostnames match "staging" (and in Real Time, I only see people looking at staging).

Comment: @Robin try to open op a console on the staging-site, switch to the network panel, and fire the event, now watch for the event-call and the page-track call, ie.: the two __utm.gif's. Look for the utmhn-parameter in both requests, do both of these include 'staging'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure, but I think it was actually just a matter of being patient, applying filters is not instantaneous (far from it).

Comment: the answer from @chow is right, it is not about being instantaneous.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem. It turns out that GA Filters only start working when you create them, not retroactively.  When you create a filter and then look at a report, you will not see the filter working unless you put a timeframe that starts after the filter was created.

It's also a good idea to add a filter to a new view since the filter permanently removes the data from the view and it can't be recovered.